# using mybaits to call store procedure,and params is Map ,but I can't get the OUT param

Tags: mybatis

when  i call this procedure, the return Map cant get the out param

procedure is:

```
create or replace procedure myDemo05(name out varchar,age in int)
as
begin
      dbms_output.put_line('age='||age);
    insert into students values(age,age,age+'');
  select 'xiaoming' into name from dual;
end;
```

the mapper.xml is:

```
  <select id="updateRet2" parameterType="java.util.LinkedHashMap" resultType="java.util.LinkedHashMap" statementType="CALLABLE">
        {
            call ${spName}
                <foreach collection="datas" index="key" item="ent"  open="(" separator="," close=")">
                    <if test="ent == '?'">
                        #{ent,mode=OUT,jdbcType=VARCHAR}
                    </if>
                    <if test="ent != '?'">
                        #{ent,mode=IN,jdbcType=INTEGER}
                    </if>

                </foreach>
        }
    </select>
```

procedure OUT param can not return!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I debug it, find as:,but it cant put "_frch_ent_0" to paramMap...
[image: this is main error !!!]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

mapper.xml should write like this!!!!!!!